# How do you check for the existence of file names with a specific string in Perl

Tags: perl

I am rewriting a Bash script in Perl in order to learn the latter.

The script creates a file using the current date in a custom format and a ".txt" extension but checks first to make sure no file with the date in question already exists.

In Bash, I accomplish this with `ls |grep $customDate` as a condition. That is, if `ls |grep $customDate` is true, a warning is issued and no file is create while if `ls |grep $customDate` is false, the file gets created with the custom date plus a ".txt" extension

How can I mimic this in Perl?

For testing purposes, I wrote the code below but it does not print out anything - even when I have created a file that meets the condition:

```
use POSIX qw( strftime );

$customDate = strftime "%Y_%m%b_%d%a", localtime;

opendir(DIR, ".") or die "$!";
my @FILES  = grep { /${customDate}*/ } readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);

print "$_\n" for @FILES;
```

I apologize if my question is unclear

Comment: seems to be working fine.

Comment: If there's a file in the current directory which has a name that contains `2016_05May_30Mo`, the code you posted will print its name as desired.

Comment: any idea why it would work for you two and not me?

Comment: The two most likely possibilities: 1) Because there's no file in the current directory with a name containing `2016_05May_30Mo`. 2) Because you posted code is different than what you ran.

Comment: If neither your own code nor either of the offered solutions are working for you then there is something else at play here. Please show how you're running your program and exactly what output you're getting

Comment: @cannonfodder If you found an answer provided here helpful, please upvote and/or mark as accepted, so that other users with a similar question can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

> "I am rewriting a Bash script in Perl in order to learn the latter."

I think you're taking the wrong approach to learning Perl, or to learning any language.

While there are always a lot of similarities between procedural languages, it is always wrong to focus on those above the differences. Programming languages must be learned from scratch if you hope ever to be able to read and write them well

I regularly see Perl code on Stack Overflow that has clearly been written by someone with the wrong head on. For instance, the clearest signs of a C programmer are

- Declaring *everything* in one block at the top of a source file
- Over-use of `scalar` and parentheses
- Under-use of the *default variable* `$_` and regular expressions
- Using the C-style `for` loop, which usually looks something like this in Perl

  ```
  my $i;

  for ($i=0; $i<=scalar(@data); $i++)
  {
      process($data[$i])
  }
  ```

  Apart from ignoring [`perlstyle`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html) completely, the author is grasping for something familiar instead of embracing the new language. In idiomatic Perl that should look like

  ```
  process($_) for @data
  ```

Reaching further, it is easy to become complacent about the consequences of phrases you may be writing glibly in the shell

You need to be aware that your shell statement

```
ls |grep $customDate
```

is starting new processes to run `/bin/ls` and `/bin/grep`, and piping information between them and back to the shell process. The Linux shell and its supporting utilities are designed to get trivial jobs done easily, but I believe they are being used too much with elaborate shell script *one-liners* that are opaque and beyond debugging

---

It's very hard to tell exactly what it is that you need your program to do, but it's looking like you want to discover whether there are any files that contain a string like `2016_05May_30Mon` in the current directory

I have to say that's a horrible date-time format and I've struggling to believe that it's what you want, but I would prefer Perl's core [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) module over [`POSIX`](https://metacpan.org/pod/POSIX) any time

In this instance I would also make use od Perl's regular expressions, the `-X` *file test operators, and Perl's [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) operator instead of `opendir`, `readdir`, `closedir`. None of those have a direct equivalent in any shell language

So, assuming that my guesses about your intention are correct, I would write this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Time::Piece;

my $dtime = localtime()->strftime('%Y_%m%b_%d%a');

say for grep { -f and /$dtime/ } glob '*.txt';
```

which isn't remotely like your translation from shell to Perl

Comment: your answer exemplifies why I abhor turning to forums for help... its pedantic tone is self-serving but ultimately, of little use to the original poster thank you very much... btw, while you kinda sorta understand what it is my first stab at perl is meant to do (after having focused WAY too much on the evil's of wanting to write a perl script that does the same thing I already have a bash script for) your answer does not work... or its beyond my skill level... either way, life is too short to waste any more time on this...

Comment: @cannonfodder: I'm sorry you feel that way. Your sentence *"I am rewriting a Bash script in Perl in order to learn the latter."* stands alone at the top of your post. I assumed that it was the main drive of your question so I addressed it with that in mind. I stand by my statement that rewriting programs from a different language is a bad way to learn a new language., although I think you can learn a *lot* by writing some simple command-line utilities, such as `ls` and `grep` without reference to the original C. And my code works fine for me: you need to run it as `perl program.pl`

Comment: @cannonfodder I think maybe you are too negative in your first comment.. In my opinion this answer is fairly well-written and may become a source of useful information for users of this forum in the future (note that answers are written for a general audience, so no need to take anything personal).

Answer (score -1):

The reason you're not getting what you expect is the `*` in the grep is looking for the last character of the "$customDate" repeated as many times as it likes (which is not what you expect from the `*` in this case).

If your file has a "somedata.txt" ext, you should update the code as such, which will look for your date string then any number of characters followed by a txt:

```
$customDate = strftime "%Y_%m%b_%d%a", localtime;

opendir(DIR, ".") or die "$!";
my @FILES  = grep { /${customDate}.*\.txt/ } readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);

print "$_\n" for @FILES;
```

Comment: 1) Don't you mean `/\Q${customDate}\E\.txt\z/` or `/^\Q${customDate}\E\.txt\z/`? 2) I don't see how that addresses the problem at all. The OP is complaining that he's not getting enough matches, and what you posted further limits what gets matched.

Comment: @ Wayne Booth: File names contain the custom date format and end in ".txt" but may also have text in between the date in the extension: `2016_05may_22.txt` or `2016_05may_30mon__payroll.txt`.

I tried what you suggest and it does not work either.

Comment: @cannonfodder  
I missed that requirement in your question. If you need something after the timestamp we need a different grep expression. Updating my answer to match